# How to create a "constant reference" getter in Dart?

Tags: dart, architecture

Say I have a class `ListContainer` that contains and manages a list that must be accessible from outside. Since managing this list is complicated, I don't want to let anyone other than `ListContainer` modify it. In C++, I would create a function that returns const reference, but in Dart, const works completely differently. Just using getter will not prevent someone from modifying the list.

So how can I provide an access to the list values without allowing to modify the list?

I'm looking for something better than creating a `getNth` function because that would also require creating methods like `length`, `map`, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `UnmodifiableListView` is what you are looking for.

check out [UnmodifiableListView Documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-collection/UnmodifiableListView-class.html)

you can use it like this:

```
List<int> _myList = [1, 2, 3];
UnmodifiableListView<int> get myList => UnmodifiableListView(_myList);
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that's what I need

Comment: You are welcome, please consider accepting this answer if it helped you.

Comment: of course, it just says I have to wait for 10 minutes before accepting it

Comment: This is great, I just wish it would issue a warning / error in compile time when trying to modify the list (e.g. `myList.add(...)`. But it rather falls at runtime.

Comment: @AlaaM. it's really the worst part of the language. The reason this is impossible is because UListView implements a regular List interface. A function that accepts a List, can receive a UListView at any moment; compiler just can't infer it. This is the textbook Liskov principle violation. I've no idea why the dart team did this, while other languages have proper immutable types.